# C# problem in append items to XML document

Tags: c#, xml, linq, appendchild

**Question**

I have a XML schema as this which i need to append more **product** to this file , i was trying `XMLdocument` and `Xdocument` both classes but didnt got any good results

```
<prodcuts>
  <product>
    <name>123</name>
    <price>123</price>
  </product>
</products>
```

**CODE:**

i was trying Xdocument class with this code

```
        XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load("F://products.xml");
        XElement parentElement = new XElement(xmldoc.XPathSelectElement("product"));
        XElement newElement = new XElement("name","32323");
        XElement newElement = new XElement("price","150");
        parentElement.Add(newElement);
        xmldoc.Save("F://products.xml");
```

**Exception**

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: other
```

I was tring `XMLdocument` class too but no results...

Where am i wrong ? ... is this problem can solved in `LINQ` or any other method ?

Comment: You are only adding the 2nd XElement ("price","150")...

Comment: That code won't compile - you've declared the same local variable twice. Please give us the *real* code.

Comment: Don't `new` the parentElement.

Comment: found the answer also thanks gody gray for moderation !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will create a new XElement under the Root node which is where I think you want it.

```
xmlDoc.Root.Add(
    new XElement("product",
        new XElement("name", "456"),
        new XElement("price", "456")));
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your sample, doesnt the path to parent need to be: prodcuts/product

```
XElement parentElement = new XElement(xmldoc.XPathSelectElement("prodcuts/product"));
```

It think parentElement is null in the example you gave